# C++ Vector.erase() last element corrupts iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I currently have a problem with vector.erase().

```
vector<gameObject> gameObjects;

for (auto it = gameObjects.end() - 1; it != gameObjects.begin();)
    {
        if ((it)->getDestroyed()) {
            it = gameObjects.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            --it;
        }
    }
```

So gameObject is the base class for everything inside the game and it has a bool flag that basically tells us if the object was destroyed. If the flag is set it should be removed from the vector.

```
class gameObject
{
protected:
    bool toBeDestroyed;
public:
    bool getDestroyed();
    void markToDestroy();
};
```

Now the first destroyed object gets removed from the vector successfully and then I get get an error that iterator is not dereferencable, pointing to the vector library at line 73(?).

I then check with the msvc debugger. In the data preview it shows that iterator points to the last/newest element of gameObjects. It is then removed (erase(it)) and AFTERWARDS the data preview doesn't change and calling it->getDestroyed() results in the error message.

Debug assertion failed! vector iterator not dereferencible.

PS: I checked cplusplus.com and vector.erase should return a new, valid iterator so I'm not sure where I'm messing it up.

€: After I was told about the erase-remove idiom I went ahead and ended up with the following, which doesn't compile. Due to my function being a member of gameObject I'm not sure how to successfully call remove_if. Thanks

```
gameObjects.erase(remove_if(gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(), gameObject::getDestroyed), gameObjects.end());
```

€2: A lot of you pointed out the first object isn't being checked. I propably should've pointed that out but the first element is ALWAYS the player and shouldn't be removed. Thanks for your comments nevertheless. I'll try with a simple forward loop without getting too fancy ^^.

€3: I tried Jonathan Mees suggested code but I get the exact same error message. I'll try and find out where exactly it happens but I can't just put a breakpoint into the erasing part anymore. Will mess around a bit.

€4: Problem was solved by removing the else {} condition and always decrementing the iterator. Thanks again for all your replies.

Comment: [erase remove idiom.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I went ahead and read up on it. Because my checking method is a member I'm not sure how to build the erase_if call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 objects in your vector and the last one is is marked as destroyed. When you call `erase`, it will return a new, valid iterator pointing at the element after the erased element. There is no element after the erased element, so the returned iterator is `gameObjects.end()`. You then continue to the top of the loop and dereference this iterator, which is not valid. You need to decrement your iterator after the erase if you want it pointing at a valid element.

One other note: If you ever wanted your first element removed, it will not be. Your loop exits when the iterator `== gameObjects.begin()`, so the first element is never checked.

Is there some reason you wanted to do this in reverse? If there is no specific reason, I would recommend you use the method recommended by @Borgleader.

Comment: First object is always the player and he should't be removed. In response to @Borgleader I tried building it similar to the wikipedia page I found but struggled with the method call due to it being a member of gameObject.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee has given an example of how to do it with C++11 lambdas.

Comment: I simply removed the else {} condition and always decrement the iterator. Works like a charm and I'm very happy :). Thanks again for taking the time. I found your explanation very easy to follow so thanks for educating me as well ^^.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is a little messed up - you're iterating backwards, ignoring the first element, and testing some elements multiple times. Might I suggest rbegin() as an alternative?

Comment: Iterating backwards is highly more efficient I was told. The first element is always the player himself. I'll try messing around with rbegin() and try if that improves things :). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[`vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) returns the:

> Iterator following the last removed element. If the iterator pos refers to the last element, the `end()` iterator is returned.

Meaning that `vector::erase` will never return `vector::begin` (unless you removed the only element in the container.) So `it` will always be dereferenced again after `vector::erase` is called. It will be dereferenced *even* if `vector::end` was returned by the call to `vector::erase` which is of course illegal.

Instead of this loop, consider using [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) which is designed for this purpose:

```
gameObjects.erase(remove_if(begin(gameObjects),
                            end(gameObjects),
                            [](const auto& i){ return i.getDestroyed(); }), end(gameObjects));
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed you try to use this in your edit. You cannot use a bare function pointer as the predicate. If you want to avoid a lambda, you should consider the use of [`mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn):

```
gameObjects.erase(remove_if(begin(gameObjects),
                            end(gameObjects),
                            mem_fn(&gameObject::getDestroyed)), end(gameObjects));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/mOcNbk)

If there's difficulty in reading that line feel free to use as many variable as you like:

```
auto p = mem_fn(&gameObject::getDestroyed);
auto result = remove_if(begin(gameObjects), end(gameObjects), p);

gameObjects.erase(result, end(gameObjects));
```

Comment: Your code is completely unreadable. Wouldn't pass review in my team.

Comment: I tried your code with the small change i->getDestroyed() but I get the same error message. I will check if the same problem persist or if something else goes wrong.

PS: Somehow I can't remove the first comment or edit it :/.

Comment: @celphy It seems like you were trying to avoid the lambda. I've updated using `mem_fn` to avoid the lambda. After looking at them both I agree that I find that more appealing. I've also included a live example demonstrating the code at work, which will hopefully help you in tinkering with the function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It has been said before that I cram too much in one line ;) I've broken it apart to hopefully satisfy your team's standards of readability.

Comment: @JonathanMee Thanks for your efforts. I'll try your solution as well. What I currently have in my code is detailled in my original post. Thanks for your time - I appreciate it immensely.

Comment: I would probably format it like this: http://pastebin.com/qdfYVJ94 so that it can be read properly. As if to prove my point, there is a missing `)` in your version (which I have left in mine so you can see where).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [blushes] Guilty as charged. I'm not sure how I feel about indenting at each open parenthesis, but I can't argue that it is more readable. I've edited to line up the `remove_if` arguments vertically, which in my mind provides the separation necessary to improve readability.

Comment: It's only select parentheses ;p

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think that's why I had a hard time with it. I want there to be some kind of hard fast rule and such a rule is difficult to put into words. I generally vertically align if a line exceeds the width of my screen, but that's wildly variable, it results in me typing the same line differently depending on the setup I'm coding in :/ Anyway, I realized that I'd gone crazy using `distance` inside a `resize` instead of just using `erase` so fixing that simplified some of the unreadability...

Comment: I was trying to group semantics. The resize and distance are tightly bound in terms of what you're doing with them, and the rest are just argument lists. Begin and end. Begin and end and predicate. Certainly you'll never see me doing vertical alignment :) One tab per indentation level - simples! (Granted my "conversion" to spaces in that pastebin is inconsistent (2 vs 3) due to rushing)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe the rule is indentation of any arguments which call another function? But it just looks stupid to indent something like: `a.resize(size(b))`

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't go that far. The line is tiny. There's a heuristic in my brain somewhere but I'm not sure what it is

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And that's my point, the intention of helping readability is a great one. But it's hard to define just what does and doesn't do that. There should be a Stack Exchange site dedicated to formatting legislation!